# How to get history of executed commands in screen terminal when we use screen command

Tags: linux, bash

I have created screen session with the help of screen command in Linux, for example I have created screen session with 5 bash terminals, after that in one of the created terminal I have sent "pwd" command to all the terminals with the help of following  actions:

1. Pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to get me to terminal prompt
2. Typed `:at "#" stuff "pwd^M"`
3. Then I sent an `ls` command: `:at "#" stuff "ls^M` to all the terminals
4. After which I want to send `pwd` command (#2) again

To send this I was looking for a history of the commands I sent to all terminals in screen (like hitting up arrow in bash to go through the history). All I got was the last command executed.

How do I get to the other commands I've executed in screen? Specifically, in this example, how do I get to the command I typed at #2?

Comment: Are you aware that `screen` only emulates a bunch of terminals and that in each of these a `bash` will be running?

Comment: Raja - I did a lot of reformatting of your question which (I believe) was asking if there is a history buffer **within screen** - not bash. If I was wrong please undo my changes.

Comment: Al G - yes you are right.. thanks for your format

Answer (score 1):

if you type:

```
history
```

you will get the history of the commands. Will it help you?

Comment: sboda - thanks for your suggestions, no use the question is like when we used vim we can get the previously executed commands in terminal prompt itself like that i am asking in screen terminal too

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `ctrl+r`. This is for bash but also works on screen provided it was already in the history.

Just do `ctrl+r` and start typing the command. It will autofill the command from the history.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get to the other commands I've executed in screen?
>   Specifically, in this example, how do I get to the command I typed at #2?

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Type <kbd>:</kbd> to get to `screen` prompt
3. Hit <kbd>↑</kbd> *twice* to go to the *second to last* command executed